# Why doesn't the delete key move a file to the trash?

Tags: nautilus, shortcut-keys, macbook

I'm running Ubuntu 12.04 on a MacBook Pro.  I have a file selected in Nautilus and I'd like to move it to the trash.

- Hitting delete takes me back in the history (like alt+left)
- Ctrl+delete does nothing
- Right clicking and the "File" menu shows "move to trash" as an option, but there's no shortcut key to the right of its entry (unlike Ctrl+C for "Copy", etc)

Why doesn't the delete key do what I expect?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because it's a Mac keyboard, the key labeled as "delete" is actually "backspace" (left delete), not "delete" (right delete).

You have to hold "fn" while hitting the delete key:  fn + delete

Comment: (Just sharing this tidbit 'cause it took me a couple minutes to realize, even after searching Ask Ubuntu.)